# Cordova not recognized

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I'm Running Windows 10 Node v5.8.0 and Cordova 6.0.0

I'm trying to install and use **Cordova**, The installation is successful but it gets installed to a file on my desktop the I ones installed a npm package (I long ago deleted that file - Node recreates it for me) instead of installing on the default location..

If I call Cordova from the local file where node has placed it, it will be recognized (but I can't create a new project next to it). and wherever I call Cordova outside of that location I'm getting this error message - 'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(This is the command I used for the installation - npm install -g cordova)

Comment: Please use "Cordova -v" command to check installed Cordova version.  Its help you know that Cordova install Globally properly or not. And that if its show, Cordova doesn't install. Please uninstall NPM, Cordova both and try to reinstall it, its work on my System.

Comment: If I'm on the path where cordova is installed then I'm getting this  - c:\Users\name\Desktop\path\path-to-cordova>cordova -v
6.0.0    if im on any other location -   C:\Windows\System32>cordova -v
'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.   -- in other words, cordova isn't recognized globally...